# pytorch Crossentropy error in simple example of NN

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

H1, I am try to make NN model that satisfy simple formula.
y = X1^2 + X2^2

But when i use CrossEntropyLoss for loss function, i get two different error message. 
First, when i set code like this

```
x = torch.randn(batch_size, 2)
y_hat = model(x)
y = answer(x).long()

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss = loss_func(y_hat, y)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

i get this message

```
RuntimeError: Assertion `cur_target >= 0 && cur_target < n_classes' failed.  at 
c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1533090623466\work\aten\src\thnn\generic/Cl
```

assNLLCriterion.c:93

Second, I change code like this

```
x = torch.randn(batch_size, 2)
y_hat = model(x)
y = answer(x).long().view(batch_size,1,1)

optimizer.zero_grad()
loss = loss_func(y_hat, y)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

then i get message like

```
RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at c:\programdata\miniconda3\conda-bld\pytorch_1533090623466\work\aten\src\thnn\generic/ClassNLLCriterion.c:21
```

How can i solve this problem? Thanks.(sorry for my English)
This is my code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

def answer(x):

    y = x[:,0].pow(2) + x[:,1].pow(2)

    return y

class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(Model, self).__init__()

        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 10)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):

        y = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        y = F.relu(self.linear2(y))

        return y

model = Model(2,1)
print(model, '\n')

loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)

batch_size = 3
epoch_n = 100
iter_n = 100

for epoch in range(epoch_n):
    loss_avg = 0

    for i in range(iter_n):

        x = torch.randn(batch_size, 2)
        y_hat = model(x)
        y = answer(x).long().view(batch_size,1,1)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = loss_func(y_hat, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        loss_avg += loss

    loss_avg = loss_avg / iter_n

    if epoch % 10 == 0:
        print(loss_avg)

    if loss_avg < 0.001:
        break
```

Can i make those dataset using dataloader in pytorch? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong loss function. `CrossEntropyLoss` is used for classification problems generally wheread your problem is that of regression. So you should use losses which are meant for regression like tasks like [Mean Squared Error Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss), [L1 Loss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.L1Loss) etc. Take a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-using-pytorch/), [this](https://hackernoon.com/linear-regression-in-x-minutes-using-pytorch-8eec49f6a0e2), [this](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/regression/main.py) and [this](https://github.com/floydhub/regression).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that CrossEntropyLoss can be usually used for classification.... Thank you very much!

Comment: If this solves your problem, consider 'accepting' the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot it!

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help.